# CodeCeption Throw an 404 exception when using click method / PHP

Tags: php, testing, laravel-4, codeception

I have codeception installed trough composer and it work fine I love it.

When I went to write my first **functional test** I got a weird problem when I try to click a specific link giving a selector css.

**I'm using Laravel4 Framework Specific**

**My Modules** on `functional.suite.yml`

```
class_name: TestGuy
modules:
    enabled: [Filesystem, TestHelper,Laravel4,Db]
```

**My Codeception Functional Test**

```
public function loginWithFacebook(TestGuy $I) {

        $password = "user1234";
        $username = "user";

        $I->wantTo('Login in the application with Facebook');
        $I->amOnPage('/');
        $I->see('Create account for free');
        $I->seeLink('| Connect with Facebook','/auth/social/facebook');
        $I->click('#facebookLogin');
        $I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('https://facebook.com/');
        $I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('/auth/social/data');
        $I->fillField('password',$password);
        $I->fillField('username',$username);
        $I->click('#facebookLogin input[type="submit"]');
        $I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('/profile/activate');
        $I->seeInDatabase('users',['username' => 'user']);
    }
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
There was 1 error:

---------
1) Failed to login in the application with facebook in FacebookLoginCest.loginWithFacebook
Sorry, I couldn't click "#facebookLogin":
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: 

Scenario Steps:
4. I click "#facebookLogin"
3. I see link "| Connect with Facebook","/auth/social/facebook"
2. I see "Create account for free"
1. I am on page "/"


  [Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException]
```

**HTML**

```
<h4>Social login</h4>
<a href="{{route('login.facebook')}}" id="facebookLogin">
         <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> | Connect with Facebook
</a>
```

How it can be possible? I even tried to change the port 80 to 8181 of where the local VH was listen with no luck.

Comment: When test fails it creates log entry in the tests/_log folder (... page.fail.html file). Check your '#facebookLogin' link there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply I saw that page but I don't understand what i have to do, You said to check the #facebookLogin attribute and it is there.